# URL Pattern Matching issue, .+ matches all after

Tags: javascript, regex, url-parsing

I am matching up stored URLs to the current URL and having a little bit of an issue - the regex works fine when being matched against the URL itself, but for some reason all sub-directories match too (when I want a direct match only of course).

Say the user stores `www.facebook.com`, this should match both `http://www.facebook.com` and `https://www.facebook.com` and it does

The problem is it is also matching sub-directories such as `https://www.facebook.com/events/upcoming` etc.

The regex for example:

```
/.+:\/\/www\.facebook\.com/
```

Matches the following:

```
https://www.facebook.com/events/upcoming
```

When it should just be matching

```
 http://www.facebook.com/
 https://www.facebook.com/
```

How can I fix this seemingly broken regex?

Comment: why didn't you add `end($)` of string.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're being really specific about what you want to match, why not reflect that in your *RegExp*?

```
/^https?:\/\/(?:(?:www|m)\.)?facebook\.com\/?$/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- http or https
- www., m. or no subdomain
- facebook.com

[Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8wselMRauYuJwftW)

**edit** to include optional trailing backslash

Comment: Hi, does the dollar sign work if it's either nothing or a trailing /? for example of course I want www.facebook.com to be targeted the same as www.facebook.com/, but different than www.facebook.com/events kinda thing? Thanks lots for the answeer

Comment: put `\/?` before the `$`, which means _"match a backslash, the last bit was optional"_

Answer (score 1):

Put an end marker `$`, like:

```
/.+:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/$/
```

but really should have a start marker `^` too, like:

```
/^https?:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/$/
```

also if you're matching the current domain, you may as well just match the `location.host` rather than `location.href`

Comment: Hi, does the dollar sign work if it's either nothing or a trailing /? for example of course I want www.facebook.com to be targeted the same as www.facebook.com/, but different than www.facebook.com/events kinda thing.

Comment: dollar is absolute end of string. you can do exactly as you say `\/?$`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a $ at the end of your regex. It's the symbol for end of string.